# How to push and error from mongodb routes to validator, user signup form

Tags: node.js, mongodb, validation, reactjs, mongoose

I have a user sign up page in react, if a user tries to signup with an already taken screenname I get a mongodb error, since i set the scheme to screenname unique, Im validating the form using validator, how can i push "this username has already been taken" in errors.screenname in my validator file

/validator.js :

```
  const isEmpty = require('lodash/isEmpty');
  const validator = require('validator');


  function validateInput(data) {
   let errors = {};

    if(validator.isEmpty(data.screenname)) {
     errors.screenname = 'This field is require';
   }

   if(validator.isEmpty(data.email)) {
      errors.email = 'This field is require';
   }

   if(!validator.isEmail(data.email)){
     errors.email = 'Email is not valid!';
   }

  if(validator.isEmpty(data.password)) {
     errors.password = 'This field is require';
   } 

   if (!validator.equals(data.password, data.passwordConfirmation)){
     errors.passwordConfirmation = 'Passwords must match!';
  }

   if(validator.isEmpty(data.passwordConfirmation)) {
      errors.passwordConfirmation = 'This field is require';
   }

   return{
     errors,
     isValid: isEmpty(errors)
    }
   }

   module.exports = validateInput;
```

User route file :

```
   const express = require('express');
   const bcrypt = require('bcrypt');
    const UserDB = require('../../model');
   const commonValidations =   require('./shared/validation/signupvalidation');
const Promise = require('bluebird');
const isEmpty = require('lodash/isEmpty');

 var mongoose = require('mongoose');

 // mongoose.connect("mongodb://localhost:27017/RockfellerDB");
 var db = mongoose.connection;

   let router = express.Router();

  function validateInput(data, otherValidations) {
    let { errors } = otherValidations(data);

   return Promise.all([
      router.get('/', function(req, res){
        UserDB.find({ screenname: data.screenname }).then(user => {
              if (user) { errors.screenname = 'This username is already taken'         }
          })
      })
   ]).then(() => {
    return {
        errors,
        isValid: isEmpty(errors)
         }
     })

     }


   router.post('/', (req, res) => {
       validateInput(req.body, commonValidations).then(({ errors, isValid }) => {

       // if form is Valid we send it to our mongo database
         if (isValid){
            const password_digest = bcrypt.hashSync(req.body.password, 10);

             var newUser = new UserDB({ 
               screenname : req.body.screenname,
                email: req.body.email,
               password: password_digest 
            }) 

            newUser.save(function(err, doc){ 
               if (err) { 
                   console.log(err);
               } else {
                   res.send(doc);
               }
           });

         } else {
            res.status(400).json(errors);
        }
      })
  });


   module.exports = router;
    return router;
```